# SQL TempDB PCI-E NVMe card - 4K or 64K

Tags: sql-server, storage, tempdb, ssd

Our primary OLTP workload is tempdb heavy (both reads & writes) based on virtual_file_stats DMV, and based on SPs all of which heavily use #tmp tables.
The server has 400GB of memory, more than enough to fit all tables in databases within in.

Tempdb was previously on a local SSD.

We recently bought and installed a [Micron](https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Micron-9100-solid-state-drive-800-GB-PCI-Express-3.0-NVMe/4278939.aspx?cm_cat=Transactional&cm_ite=SPS_Order_Confirm-_-Body-_-Browse_Products-_-SpsOrderConfirmation&cm_pla=EMTRAN044adu0000P0000&cm_ven=Email&etsi=11720787&etsu=200032466) PCI-E card, and placed SQL (2016 Ent) tempdb data and log files on it.

However, I did not see a great improvement in performance, for some workloads it was even worse. The vendor specs lists 4K read-write speeds, whereas SQL uses 64KB (right?).

Before I ask the SAN team to run benchmarks on the existing SSD vs new PCI-E disks, would it make sense to format the PCI-E disk as 4KB block size, instead of 64KB.. or does it not make difference for tempdb ?

Comment: the drive is benchmarked using 4KB blocks because that is what most people use.  You should format the drive (and any other drives that have SQL data or log files, if possible) to 64KB, because that is how SQL works with data on disk.

Comment: Additionally ... The way SAN controllers work, you may lose performance on writes. A SAN will acknowledge the write once it hits controller cache instead of when it hits disk. My Pure SAN outperformed a SANdisk Fusion card for writes.